# Attach CSS class issue during loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to attach class 'active' to a selected `li` after page redirected.
The issue now is that, after I clicked on the `li`, the CSS class was attached to previous `li`.
Example: I clicked on `li` index 1 and clicked on `li` index 5. Class was attached to `li` index 1 and if I click on `li` index 3 the CSS class will be attached to `li` index 5 after redirecting.

The CSS class are from bootstrap

```
<div  id="mainnav">
  <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" role="tablist" Orientation="Horizontal"
            CssClass="nav nav-pills"  ForeColor="Black" RenderingMode="List"
            IncludeStyleBlock="False">

                     <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="nav nav-pills"/>
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="MainNavStyle"/>
                 </asp:Menu>
              </div>  

  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#mainnav li').click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                var liMainIndex = $(this).index();
//get selected main navigation bar li index and save it in cookie 
                $.cookie("selectednav", liMainIndex);
            });
            $('#SideBar li').click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
//get selected side navigation bar li index and save it in cookie 
                var liSideIndex = $(this).index();
                $.cookie("selectedsidenav", liSideIndex);
            });
        });

        $(function loadnav() {
            debugger
//retrive selected ul li index from cookie and add class to the li
            var liMainIndex = $.cookie("selectednav");
            $("#mainnav li").removeClass("active");
            $("#mainnav li:eq(" + liMainIndex + ")").addClass("active");
            var liSideIndex = $.cookie("selectedsidenav");
            $("#SideBar li:eq(" + liSideIndex + ")").addClass("active");
        });
```

HTML markup

```
<div role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills" id="ctl00_Menu1" style="float: left;">
:before
<ul class="level1 nav nav-pills static" tabindex="0" role="menubar"
    style="position: relative;width: auto; float: left;">
::before
  <li role="menuitem" class="static active" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<a class="level1 MainNavStyle static" href="sGroup.aspx?mainid=0&sub=Scale Group"
   tabindex="-1">Store</a>
</li>
<li role="menuitem" class="static" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<a class="level1 MainNavStyle static"
   href="../Data/DepMa.aspx?mainid=1&sub=Department & Main Group" tabindex="-1">
  Data
</a>
</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
::after
</ul>
:after
</div>
```

Comment: Why you are using cookie? It might be the reason for your issue.

Comment: i only thought of that to store the value temporary.Maybe you have a better solution to retrieve the values?

Comment: ok solved it by myself. using querystring. i removed all the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            //debugger
            var liMainIndex;
            liMainIndex = '<%= Request.QueryString("mainid")%>'

            $("#mainnav ul li").eq(liMainIndex).addClass("active");
            var liSideIndex = '<%= Request.QueryString("subid")%>'

            $("#SideBar ul li").eq(liSideIndex).addClass("active");          
        });
```

The subid and mainid will be generated from code behind during pageload.
So all i have to do is just to get the IDs from the address bar and assign the index value to

```
  $("#SideBar ul li").eq(liSideIndex).addClass("active");
```

and add a class do it. problem solved. I hope this will helps